# JavaScript img onload - progressive jpg/jpeg

Tags: javascript, jpeg, onload, progressive

Is there a way to **detect loading of each step of progressive JPEG** (or at least the first one)?

At the moment onload() event is fired once the final (high quality) image is loaded.

*Tested in Chrome 48.*

Comment: Highly doubtful and incredibly specific to the image format. I'd say no.

Comment: Hello, I wanted to know if you ever found something for this ? Even if it doesn't detect each step, but at least  Iwould like to have an event telling me when the first step has been reached (aka something is displayable)

Comment: Hi, no unfortunately this became a low priority task for me and I didn't make any further researches.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't an event for it.

There's `loadstart` event that tells you when the browser makes a request, but it doesn't mean there's any data yet.

You can keep polling `.naturalHeight` property to observe if the browser knows image dimensions, which would mean that at least it has got some data.

A desperate option, and most likely too inefficient in most cases, is to download the image using XHR/fetch (which allows you to observe download progress), and then keep setting the partial data as `Blob` on the image element. I use this hack to demonstrate progressive image loading in slow-motion on [ImageOptim API demo page](https://imageoptim.com/api).

Another option is to use a `ServiceWorker`, and pass through a chunked stream, and observe how much of the stream has been sent. In case of JPEG you can safely assume that 15% of the file is enough to render a usable preview of the file.